# Pandas - keep track of value after applying linear regression on other values

Tags: pandas, linear-regression

I am trying to apply linear regression to a series of variables in my pandas dataframe, excepting player_id, which is only a way to track the player being predicted.

```
print (df.info())

player_id        1601 non-null int64
X1               1601 non-null float64
X2               1601 non-null float64
X3               1601 non-null float64
X4               1601 non-null float64
X5               1601 non-null float64
X6               1601 non-null float64
X7               1601 non-null float64
X8               1601 non-null float64
Y                1601 non-null float64
```

this is how I try to declare my variables:

```
df = df[['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'X7', 'X8', 'Y']]

X = df.drop(axis=1, columns=['Y'])
# normalize data
X = X.astype('float32') / 255.

# independent variable
y = df['Y']
# normalize data
y = y.astype('float32') / 255.

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)

y_hat = model.predict(X)
```

---

The question is: once I have my array of predicted values, how do I track them back to each player_id, in order to know to which player the predicted value refers to?

---

Example:

To which player_id `max(network.predict(X))` refers to?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
for i, value in enumerate(list(y_hat.flatten())):
    print (df.iloc[i]['player_id'])
    df['prediction'].iloc[i] = value.astype('float32')
```

Answer (score 0):

it will return list of values in same order as the X you supplied. So for i<sup>th</sup> row in X, i<sup>th</sup> value of y_hat is the prediction.

Comment: thank you. this will get me the index. but I don't need rows. I need to get one value, player_id, in that row

Comment: for example: to which player_id `max(network.predict(X)` refers to?

Comment: I don't know what model/library etc you are using.  But you would always want to first to tie predictions to corresponding X before doing 'max' on them.   if you only try to analyze a string of prediction without indexes, you can't know who it belongs to.  Basically the libraries I know will give you predictions in the order you provided data, and you have to link it back before doing anything else. so. for df[index, X1, X2...] when you get predictions you attach them to your df as df[index, Y_hat]